# Removing text from string from right side using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove text in string which is dynamic. E.g my string looks like this;

> 2.5 mm 4 items

OR

> £1,600 - £2,000 1 item

I want only **2.5 mm** , and remove all the number value **4 items** OR in other case just keep **£1,600 - £2,000** and remove everything after space , please note that these are dynamic values that's why I am not hard coding "1 item" in the code below.

I tried using this but its just removing the text items and not the dynamic value that comes before this.

```
var out1 = string.replace(/items/g, "");
```

Please advise

Comment: Is it always `...item(s)`?

Comment: @Luca yes its always {Price range}{Space}{Numeric Value}{Space}{items}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\d+ items?`

```js
var text1 = "2.5 mm 4 items"

var text2 = "£1,600 - £2,000 1 item"

console.log(text1.replace(/\d+ items?/g, ""), text2.replace(/\d+ items?/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

use str.replace(/ \d+ items?/, '');

```js
var str1 = '2.5 mm 4 items';
var str2 = '£1,600 - £2,000 1 item';

console.log(str1.replace(/ \d+ items?/, ''));
console.log(str2.replace(/ \d+ items?/, ''));
```

\d+ is for any digits (1 or more) and items? will match item and items (0 or 1 s)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '2.5 mm 4 items';
text = text.split(' ');

text.pop();
text.pop();

text = text.join(' ');
```